# Linear Regression Percentage Increase/Decrease

Tags: regression

I am trying to find out a way to display the percentage increase or decrease to my customers using y = mx + b

```
[m] => -3.1817815606309E-9
[b] => 4509.1022466333
[r] => -0.60473807847473
[r2] => 0.36570814355731
```

Some data:

```
x,y

1410375600000,21.91
1410379200000,21.99
1410382800000,21.41
1410386400000,22.18
1410390000000,22.65
1410393600000,22.01
1410397200000,21.27
1410400800000,21.13
1410404400000,21.92
1410408000000,22.40
1410411600000,22.08
1410422400000,21.86
1410426000000,22.29
1410429600000,22.27

x = time since epoch in milliseconds
y = prices
```

How do I find out the rate to which it's increase/decreasing? I have been playing with r2 * 100 and have been getting ok results with it but I am not sure I am doing this right.

Ultimately if my first values are around ~\$25 and my last values around ~\$20, I want 20% decrease as my answer.

thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking for.

Comment: I am not sure how can I make it clearer... I have a graph with plots and a positive slope. I want to know how much of a inc/dec there is between the start of my slope and the end.

Comment: That's at least somewhat clearer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this isn't a great model for predicting or understanding prices. I think you know that though, and you're just looking for SOMETHING to tell your customers, right?

m = rate of change in x per unit of y. So for each millisecond, price has decreased by 3.1817815606309E-9 dollars.

If you started at \$25, and 30 days pass, you'd expect prices to decrease by $m * (1000*60*60*24*30)$ units. Or \$8.247. $1 - (25-8.247)/25$ is a 33% decrease.

For a general formula for $d$ days, $P_0$ initial price: 
$1 - (P_0 -(m*(1000*60*60*24*d)))/P_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try to make some sense out of it. Just to make sure, I am not trying to predict anything. I already have all the data I need. I just need to show how much of a change there is between the beginning of the trendline and the end. I am not sure I am using this right.

Comment: Sure, let me know if I could have been clearer. The 1000*60*60*24 was to convert milliseconds into days.

Comment: I am not sure what you suggested helps me. You say I "expect" prices to dec/inc. I don't expect anything because I already have the values. I am not predicting anything. I have all the prices already. How would that work? If I use, (1000∗60∗60∗24∗30), that's 30 days in the future. My dates are all in the past.

Comment: I used that word because I thought you were predicting things. By expect I simply meant that m is the rate of change on the trend line. Just use the formula I gave you to give your customers the % decline number.

Comment: Shouldn't I include an ending point if I already have it to calculate the rate of inc/dec? By using the initial price as P0 and plugging it back in the formula, I am using the slope to "predict" what the ending value should be. However, I already know it. I guess I am just confused.

Comment: You have 2 options. 1) % change = (last-first)/first. 2) The option you came here for help with, use the linear model's slope. But for option 2 you need to choose an initial point. You came here asking for help with option 2, but given your needs maybe you should just use option 1.

Comment: I agree with @jarfa. From your post, I would say you are interested in point 2) of his comment, that is, the average percentage change in the price when x goes up by 1 millisecond (and here I would suggest you to rescale this variable and transform it in some more manageable scale...but of couse, this depends on what you are studying). However, from your comments it seems you are interested in point 1) of Jarfa's comment. In that case, no regression is necessary and I would suggest to just use the formula he wrote: % change = (last value of y-first value of y)/first value of y.

Comment: I think the entire question needs to be reworked.  It's not clear at all what the OP is actually trying to do or what he is asking.  OP, can you modify your post to make it crystal clear what you are doing?

Comment: @Fuca26 would it make any sense for him to plug the first and last timestamp in to the regressions formula to get the model's first and last value to calculate percent change? If so, how would you describe that percentage in words? The "expected/predicted percent change" over this time period? Contrasting this with using actual first/last value. eg First==Last but overall downward trend would be uinformative.